# Wordpress register_post_type function to act the way I want

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating my own posts in WordPress.
however, I have hit a little problem and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Ok, so first thing first.
I created 2 new post type 
(bc I want to design them different than the regular post )

So total I have 3 type of posts:

"Post" (wordpress default)

"Review"

"Best"

The problem is when creating a category and sub-category.
and assign it to the default post.

the url turn up good:
www.domainName.com/Categoty/Subcategory/postname/

How even no matter what i do with my new post types

they show up as:

www.domainName.com/Review/post-name/

www.domainName.com/best/post-name/

I want them to have the same behavior as the default post.

So when I create a new post-review: 
I want the url will be:
www.domainName.com/category/sub-category/post-name/

```
function toolsyouwishfor_post_types() {
    // Best Post Type
    register_post_type( 'best', array(
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'category'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor', 'excerpt','thumbnail','custom-fields','post-formats'),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Best Type Posts',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Best Type Post',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Best Type Post Post',
            'all_items' => 'All Best Posts',
            'singular_name' => 'Best Post'
        )  
    ));

    // Review Post Type
    register_post_type( 'review', array(
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'category'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor', 'excerpt','thumbnail','custom-fields','post-formats'),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Review Post',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Review',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Review Post',
            'all_items' => 'All Review Posts',
            'singular_name' => 'Review Post'
        )  
    ));
 // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses/%course%'),
}


add_action('init', 'toolsyouwishfor_post_types');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way using this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Install it and go to the Tools > Permalinks page. Scroll down to under your post type under Permalink Settings for Custom Post Types and change /%postname%/ to /%category%/%postname%/ for each post type you want to set this property to. In the screenshot the post type is called cpt_services. See screenshot:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woXJE.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The thing is, that I need it to behave like the post-type, and not just change the URL.

So so if i call get_the_permalink() or any other function it should return what it would return on a regular post page.

Comment: I changed my answer.